# Don't understand why I receive null

Tags: java

So here is my `Superhero` class:

```
public class Superhero {

  public int strength;
  public int powerUp;
  public int defaultStrength = 10;
  public String name;

  public Superhero(String name) {
     this.strength = 10;
     System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
  }

  public Superhero(String name, int strength) {
     if (strength >= 0) {
      this.strength = strength;
      System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
     } else {
      System.out.println("Error. Strength cannot be < 0");
     }
  }

  public void setStrength( int strength ) {        
     this.strength = strength;
  }

  public int getStrength() {
    return strength;
  }

  public void powerUp(int powerUp) {
    this.strength += powerUp;
  }

}
```

Here is my `Fight` class the problem here is when I run it I get back that the winner result is `null` and I don't understand why it is doing that.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Fight {

  public static void main (String args[]) {

    Superhero gambit = new Superhero( "Gambit" );

    Superhero groot = new Superhero( "Groot", 79);

    System.out.println( "Gambit's strength is: " + gambit.strength);
    System.out.println( "Groot's strength is: " + groot.strength);
    System.out.println("The winner of the fight is: " + fight(gambit, groot));

  } 

  static String fight(Superhero a, Superhero b)
  {
    if (a.strength > b.strength)
    {
       return a.name;
    } else
    { 
       return b.name;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Look at your constructor:

```
public Superhero(String name) {
   this.strength = 10;
   System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
}
```

That sets the instance field `strength`, but doesn't do *anything* with the `name` instance field. Your other constructor is the same. You need to include:

```
this.name = name;
```

to copy the value from the parameter into the instance variable. Do this in both constructors. Otherwise you just end up with the default value for `name`, which is a null reference.

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend making your fields private and adding a `getName()` method to retrieve the name from else your `fight` method. I'd *also* throw an exception instead of just printing out an error message if the strength is below 0, and *also* I'd make the constructor which doesn't take a `strength` parameter just chain to the one that does:

```
public Superhero(String name) {
    this(name, 10);
}

public Superhero(String name, int strength) {
    if (strength < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("strength cannot be negative");
    }
    this.strength = strength;
    this.name = name;
    System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
}
```

(The message displayed by the constructor is a bit odd, given that it's only listing a single name, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your constructors:

```
public Superhero(String name) {
   this.strength = 10;
   System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
}

public Superhero(String name, int strength) {
   if (strength >= 0) {
      this.strength = strength;
      System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
   } else {
      System.out.println("Error. Strength cannot be < 0");
   }
}
```

Your constructors have an argument of a `String name`, but you never set the instance variable to a value. The default value of an uninitialized variable that contains an object is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You never set the name in any of the constructors of Superhero. To fix the first constructor, for example:

```
public Superhero(String name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.strength = 10;
   System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never assigning the "incoming" name to the attribute field "name" of your class. So the later one stays null.

Btw: you really want to read those exception traces carefully. They provide all the information that you need to have in order to figure whats going on.

Final note: consider using the keyword final for the attributes of your class. That way you would have not run into this problem; as the compiler would have told you that the field "name" isn't initialized in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a getter method that returns the String name in your superhero class, then call that method within your Fight class. I would also suggest changing your global variables in your superhero class from public to private, so they are only accessible within that class.

EDIT: As stated in another answer, your constructor that takes name as an argument is never assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the values of name variable in the constructor, use this

```
public Superhero(String name) {
   this.strength = 10;
   this.name = name;
   System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
}

public Superhero(String name, int strength) {

   this.name = name;
   if (strength >= 0) {
      this.strength = strength;
      System.out.println("The Superheroes available are :" + name);
   } else {
      System.out.println("Error. Strength cannot be < 0");
   }
}
```